# Secure Alternative Way to Pass Infromation to a Payment Provider Without Using Form/POST

Tags: php, html, api, payment

A while back, when dinosaurs roamed the earth, I cobbled together a payment processing series of pages for my website.

You can see this marvel of prehistoric ingenuity in this museum
https://www.lawnbagsigns.com/

How it works is that it's a series of three pages, which pass the information from one another through a  using POST. The variables also get stored in a SESSION because why the hell not. I love redundancies.

It's done this way because that's how the original payment processing was done, and the payment processor I am currently using (Bambora/Beanstream) had an API which required that I submit a POST form to their website with all the relevant information, including passwords and such.

The issue is that you can see all that information when you "inspect source code". I never really minded it, because the payment password is different from the login info I need to access their terminal. I never worried about it, because what is someone going to do with it? Send me money? Great, go ahead and do it.

The problem is that actually people did steal this info and are using it... to send me money? Great problem, right? Well, turns out, what they are doing is that they are "carding". For those that don't know, "carding" is when some hackers steal some credit card numbers, and then use a poorly cobbled payment processing site like mine to check if the cards work/have money on them. I don't get to keep any of the money they send my way, I just get to dispute the thousand dollars transaction bills, and "too many emails sent per hour" messages because every transaction sends out a receipt via an email. And they do about a thousand or so attempts every time they do this. Per hour.

I've tried a couple of methods to deter them. Having minimum payment amounts for example, setting up a captcha. In desperation I would delete the .php files from the server, but they would still be sending out thousands of processing requests per hour. What I figure happened is that they have their own site somewhere running a script that goes through the card numbers and uses the info they stripped from the "view source code" page to send the transaction requests on my behalf. Which means that I have to find someway to pass the info to their API without exposing my payment credentials on the website (yes, I will be changing the passwords for it, obviously)

The service provider has a new API with new documentation doing it through Javascript, which bipasses these issues. However, this would require re-writing this portion and I have a new website in the works. I just need something that works in the meantime that won't have this kind of an issue.

TLDR is there a simple way to send information over to another website to be processed, without exposing it for everyone to see via the Form/POST ?

Comment: Javascript is not a new way, `xhttp` has existed for ages and you have always been able to send requests like this. It is UI dependent, do you want the page to refresh? Yes: use a form. No: use JS. The concept doesn't change, you're sending a http request somewhere, that can be your back-end that collects the information or an external server.

Comment: @Jaquarh I'm not sure if you understood the issue. I'm not saying Javascript is a new way, just that the Payment Processing API is using it now, and before it used POST/FORM method. And the issue with the POST/Form method is that I have to send my id/password combo over to the processor.... and that anyone who Views Source can see it and use it to run carding scripts from their website

Answer (score 1):

> *is there a simple way to send information over to another website to be processed, without exposing it for everyone to see via the Form/POST*

That's how PHP is supposed to work. You do your backend stuff first - such as processing a form or communicating with an external service (payment gateway), and then you generate the HTML template or redirect to a HTML page.

I'll show it on a basic example:

1. HTML page contains a form
2. and submits the data to a PHP script
3. PHP sends the received form data to an external service (such as payment gate)
4. and redirects to a thank you HTML page

form.html

```
<form action="/submit.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

submit.php

```
<?php
$firstname = $POST['firstname'] ?? null;

/*
 * some external services publish their SDK
 * or you can call their API using the PHP CURL functions
 */
$paymentGateSdk->sendFirstName($firstName);

/*
 * after you've sent it to the payment gate
 * redirect the user to the thank you page
 */
header('Location: /thank-you.html');
```

thank-you.html

```
<p>Thank you for shopping with us</p>
```

---

There are also MVC frameworks such as Symfony or Laravel, that help you to organize code into meaningful layers (model, view, controller - as the abbreviation suggests), but that's a pretty broad topic on its own, so I'll leave it here for anyone else to answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't think you got the crux of my issue. The issue is that the API I'm using requires that I send them an id/password combo. Which, when I'm sending it via POST, anyone can see it. And carders are using this information to run scripts from their websites. I want to know if there is a way to hide this information, or pass the request in way that doesn't make it visible to everyone what is going on

Comment: @dasick You can generate a POST request in PHP using [CURL functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). This way it always stays hidden from your users.